# How can I quickly create all folders named {Single|Multi}Lane_{Single|Dual}Carriageway_{USA|Europe}

Tags: bash, zsh, directory, mkdir

In Bash or Zsh, what is the shortest way to create a folder for each possible combination of substrings? Is there maybe even a notation such as

```
mkdir {Single|Multi}Lane_{Single|Dual}Carriageway_{USA|Europe}
```

which should result in the creation of

```
SingleLane_SingleCarriageway_USA
MultiLane_SingleCarriageway_USA
SingleLane_DualCarriageway_USA
MultiLane_DualCarriageway_USA
SingleLane_SingleCarriageway_Europe
MultiLane_SingleCarriageway_Europe
SingleLane_DualCarriageway_Europe
MultiLane_DualCarriageway_Europe
```

My substrings also may have more than two options, such as `{USA, Europe, Asia}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `|`s in your command to `,`:

```
mkdir {Single,Multi}Lane_{Single,Dual}Carriageway_{USA,Europe}
```

[3.5.1 Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion)